# Setting the default value inside the input field in the antd library after calling the function in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have the `loadProfile` function that I want to call in `useEffect`. If the `loadProfile` function is called within `useEffect`, the name `Mario` should be displayed inside the input `name` field. How can I set the default value in the `antd` library inside input? I try to use `defaultValue` but the input field remains empty.

Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-311hn1

```
const App = () => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        role: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        buttonText: 'Submit'
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        loadProfile();
    }, []);

    const loadProfile = () => { 
        setValues({...values, role, name="Mario", email});
    }

    const {role, name, email, buttonText} = values;



    const updateForm = () => (
        <Form
            {...layout}
            name="basic"
            initialValues={{
                remember: true,
                name: name
            }}
        >
            <Form.Item
                label= 'Name'
                name='name'
                rules={[
                    {
                        required: true,
                        message: 'Please input your name!',
                    },
                ]}
            >
                <Input 
                    defaultValue= {name}
                />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item
                label="Email"
                name="email"
                value={email}
                rules={[
                    {
                        type: 'email',
                        required: true,
                        message: 'Please input your email!',
                    },
                ]}
            >
                <Input 
                />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                    {buttonText}
                </Button>
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    );

    return (
        <>
            <Row>
                <Col span={24} style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                  <h1>Private</h1>
                  <p>Update Form</p>
                </Col>
            </Row>
                {updateForm()}
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it, but your setValues is incorrect and it doesn't actually do anything.         `setValues({...values, name: "Mario"});` Use a colon instead. Your state always had name being '' instead of `Mario`. After that change your state is at least correct (for some reason the `defaultValue` does not work though, just change it to the string `test` and see that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Diesel I changed it to string `defaultValue= "Mario"`. But it still doesn't work

Comment: Posted an answer and working example for you.

Comment: @Diesel But the rules stopped work                                                              `rules={[
  {
     required: true,
     message: 'Please input your name!',
  },
 ]}`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to make three changes to your code. This is a working component, I also extracted your component and put the appropriate state in there. I also made it functional.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tlm1qg

First change

`setValues({...values, role, name="Mario", email});`

to

`setValues({...values, name: "Mario"});`

This will properly set the state.

Second change:

Next, you should notice that if you set `defaultValue="test123"` it still won't work, something is up. Remove `name` from `Form.Item` and boom it works. `test123` shows up. But if you put `values.name` in there, it still doesn't work!

Third Change:

That's because `defaultValue` only sets that value right when the component is created, not on mount. So you have to use `value={values.name}` and it will set that value once on mount per your `useEffect`

In the demo component I also added a change handler for you so the user can type in there, if you wanted that.

---

If you look at the [FAQ](https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#Why-is-component-defaultValue-not-working-when-inside-Form.Item?) for Ant Design it says:

> Components inside Form.Item with name property will turn into
> controlled mode, which makes defaultValue not work anymore. Please try
> initialValues of Form to set default value.

Ant Design is taking over control - so you don't have to set `value={name}` and `onChange`.

You want to set the values AFTER the component is created. So to do that you need

```
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      username: 'Mario',
    });
  }, []);
```

and in you Form make sure you add:

```
    <Form
        {...layout}
        name="basic"
        initialValues={{
            remember: true,
        }}
        form={form} // Add this!
    >
```

I updated my online example.

Big picture - when you want to set the value after creation, use this hook and `form.setFieldsValue`